# Find FontName from a TTF file in UBUNTU

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, fonts, truetype

I need to programmatically install (In Ubuntu) few hundreds of fonts for my application (Developed in Ruby on rails) and track the font names installed while installing.

So i need a tool or some library in UBUNTU which takes **TTF file as input and provide the Font-Name** as output.

Even if there is some way in ruby (GEM OR anything which can help) to find the font-name with given TTF file, will be great help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you searched for? I find it implausible that searching for "ruby ttf parser" returned zero useful results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically i used fop-ttfreader to get the details from a TTF file..

```
fop-ttfreader fontfile.ttf xmlfile.xml
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/fop-ttfreader.1.html

So now this xml file can be parsed and get the font details.

This looks like its increased to 2 steps, instead as suggested by djangodude, it can be done in a simple code by parsing ourself. In my case it will be a one time process like a rake.. So this helped me to finish my job.. :P

Hope this may help someone.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine there ought to be a ruby font parser of some sort that could do this, but if you have a little skill you could probably make your own pretty easily. You'll need two important pieces of info:

- [Data structure for TTF file header](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm)
- [Data structure for the 'name' table](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm) (where the font name is stored)

Read the header, locate the 'name' table, search the 'name' table for a nameID 4 entry ("full name", e.g. "My Cool Font Bold Italic"). Or maybe nameID 1 if you just want the family name ("My Cool Font").

The data structures are pretty simple and should not be much trouble at all for even a beginner developer to understand and parse.

Comment: Thanks djangodude. This links helped to understand the structure of font files. But i ahve found another solution which might be little messy.. :P  Anyway posting it here below... :)

Answer (score 1):

The [ttfunk gem](https://github.com/prawnpdf/ttfunk) will do most of the heavy lifting without you needing to do any parsing yourself:

```
require 'ttfunk'

file = TTFunk::File.open("some/path/myfont.ttf")
puts "name: #{file.name.font_name.join(', ')}"
```

(excerpt from the readme in said gem)