# Substitute node labels with emoji using networkX in Python

Tags: python, data-visualization, networkx

I am using networkX to draw a network plot from a distance matrix(emoji_sim, a DataFrame). Here is the code:

```
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.array(emoji_sim))
nx.draw(G, edge_color='silver', node_color='lightsalmon', with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

I know there is a way to relabel the nodes as:

```
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, dict(zip(range(len(G.nodes())), range(1, len(G.nodes())+1))))
```

But I want to substitute the nodes label with images(possibly read from files or using Python Emoji package). Is there any way to do that? Thanks a lot!

To clarify, I am trying to substitute the actual circle with images.

Comment: Do you want the label to change, or the actual circle that's plotted for the node to change?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I am trying to change the circle to images.

Comment: I don't think it's built in, but I don't think it's incredibly hard.  I don't have time to work up the whole solution, but here is a hint that hopefully will lead someone else to fill in details: you can use networkx to get the node positions.  Then use matplotlib to plot the images at those positions.  Then draw the edges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind it is not very difficult but in order to get it to be displayed (at least on ubunto) it gave me some hard time as not all fonts support emoji. I shall display the straight forward way then some links that helped me in the end (maybe you will not need those).

From emoji [cheat sheet](http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/) from the [emoji python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/emoji) I picked up three to be shown as an example and here is the code.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([0,1,2])
n0 = emoji.emojize(':thumbsup:',use_aliases=True)
n1 = emoji.emojize(':sob:',use_aliases=True)
n2 = emoji.emojize(':joy:',use_aliases=True)
labels ={0:n0,1:n1,2:n2}
nx.draw_networkx(G,labels=labels, node_color = 'w', linewidths=0, with_labels=True, font_family = 'Symbola' ,font_size = 35)    
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Difficulties encountered:**

> 1- My machine is on ubunto 14.04, I could not display any emoji they always appeared as rectangles

Installed needed font **Symbola** using the following command [(mentioned here)](https://www.kirsle.net/blog/entry/make-emoji-work-in-linux):

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
```

> 2- Maplotlib (which networkx calls to draw) is not using the installed font.

From several useful discussions [1](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3590) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085867/matplotlib-font-not-found) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183433/available-font-family-entry-for-draw-networkx-labels) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992084/find-fontname-from-a-ttf-file-in-ubuntu) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726852/how-to-use-a-random-otf-or-ttf-font-in-matplotlib) [6](https://superuser.com/questions/476082/matplotlib-font-manager-py-font-finding-error) I copied and pasted the .tff font file of Symbola in the default matplotib directory (where it fetches for fonts to use).

```
cp /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-ancient-scripts/Symbola605.ttf /usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf
```

Then I had to delete fontList.cache file for the new font to be loaded.

```
rm ~/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache
```

**Note**

You can have different views by changing the input to the draw_networkx e.g. not sending the `linewidths` will show circular border for each node, also if you want a specific background color for nodes change the `color_node` from white to a color that you want ... for more details check the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html?highlight=draw_networkx).

Comment: Take a look at `nx.draw_networkx_labels` ([documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html))  and also it's usually better to predefine the position `pos` with `pos=nx.spring_layout(G)` or some other preferred layout.  This let's you do multiple things to a plot without it changing the locations of the nodes.

Comment: Each time `spring_layout` runs, it starts from a random initial condition.  So if you want to do multiple colors, or put some nodes on top of others, or just do anything that would involve calling more than one plot command, the whole network will be repositioned.  So you're right it's not necessary in this case, but for most elaborate things you might try, it's useful.  Since you had set the linewidth to zero and node color to white rather than just drawing the label, it looked like you weren't as experienced with the networkx drawing commands as other parts. I thought I'd mention it as well.

Comment: Ah it is clearer now, thanks for the hint. I shall take it into consideration from now on.

Comment: I suppose also here if I had edges they would not appear. Which would prove to be more important to draw labels separately. EDIT Actually I have tried but the edges appear even if the linewidths is set to zero.