# Generate graph in python with images as edge lables

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx, pygraphviz, pydot

I want to generate a graph, where there is an image on the edge label instead of text. I am trying to do this on the pydot, but it allows me to add only text as the label.

Is there any alternative which will help me to do this?

Comment: Here's a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190985/substitute-node-labels-with-emoji-using-networkx-in-python